# Quota exceeded for Queries and limit Queries per day of service calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api, quota

Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Queries' and limit 'Queries per day' of service 'calendar-json.googleapis.com'

This error occurs on some existing software which was working fine until yesterday. Now we are getting this error after the first request. It seems the limit is set to 1 now, but that looks like a bug from Google, as the limits are set much higher in the API console.

Quota Name                           Limit
Queries per day                      500,000
Queries per minute per user          5,000

Anyone have experience with this? Anything we can do or do we have to just wait for Google to fix this? :-)

If anyone has more info or pointers on where we can look to fix this, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, it's definitely a problem on Google side.

A lot of people experienced it: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/182497593